# if statement to exit from program

Tags: java, if-statement, binaryfiles

Suppose that you have a binary file that contains numbers whose type is either int or double. You dont know the order of the numbers in the file, but their order is recorded in a string at the beginning of the file. The string is composed of the letters i for int, and d for double, in the order of the types of the subsequent numbers. The string is written using the method writeUTF.

For example the string "iddiiddd" indicated that the file contains eight values, as follows: one integer, followed by two doubles, followed by two integers, followed by three doubles.

My problem is that, if there are more letters in the string than numbers, how can I create an if statement telling the user there is an error in the file they are trying to read?

I tried using this, where "count" is the amount of numbers and "length" is the length of the string, but this did not work.

```
    if(count!=length){
        System.out.println("Error in file: Length of string and numbers are not equal");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

the rest of my code is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input file: ");
    String fileName=keyboard.next();
    int int_num_check=0;
    double double_num_check=9999999999999999999999999999.999999999;
    int int_num=0;
    double double_num=0.0;
    int count=0;

    try{
        FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream input=new ObjectInputStream(fi);

        String word=input.readUTF();
        int length=word.length();

        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){

            if(word.charAt(i)=='i'){
                int_num=input.readInt();
                System.out.println(int_num);
                if(int_num>int_num_check){
                    int_num_check=int_num;
                }
            }

            else if(word.charAt(i)=='d'){
                double_num=input.readDouble();
                System.out.println(double_num);
                if(double_num<double_num_check){
                    double_num_check=double_num;
                }
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Error");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            count++;

        }

        System.out.println("count: "+count);
        System.out.println("length "+length);

        if(count!=length){
            System.out.println("Error in file: Length of string and numbers are not equal");
            System.exit(0);
        }

         String checker=input.readUTF();
            if(!checker.equals(null)){
                System.out.println("Error");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        input.close();
        fi.close(); 

}
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(EOFException e){

        System.out.println("Largest integer: "+int_num_check);
        System.out.println("Smallest double: "+double_num_check);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
        }


}
```

}

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your application will throw an exception at `input.readInt();` (or double) when there are no more things to read. You can catch the Exception when this occurs and handle that.

Comment: I have included all the exceptions that I can think of, its just that when I test this program and expect an error I dont get the error, and I would like to know why I dont get one?

Comment: Can you post the file's content?

Comment: The file says "idid   8   4.33316   2 " @MateusViccari

Comment: And when you run it, does it just hang?  Or does it throw a `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: It just hangs and does nothing, it prints as if there is no error @DavidWallace

Comment: Right, I thought so.  What happens if you call `hasNextInt()` before the call to `nextInt()`?  This should return `true` or `false` depending on whether an integer value is available.

Comment: How did you create your file? Because if you are using an objectInputStream to read the values, it should have been written with an ObjectOutputStream, which means you can't just open it with a text editor. I tried with your code and i got EOFException with the contents you said you have in the file. Im gonna answer with a code that should produce the correct file.

Comment: It was written with an ObjectOutputStream. I did not write it myself, it was given to me to practice my code on for an upcoming test @MateusViccari

Answer (score 0):

If there are more letters than there are numbers, you probably reached the end of file (eof).  Check for eof after each file read for a number and report an error if you got to eof before all the expected numbers have been read.

Comment: But am I not already doing that? Or am I doing that incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe the problem is the way your file was created. Try creating it with this code:

```
try {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/file.txt"));
    oos.writeUTF("idid");
    oos.writeInt(8);
    oos.writeDouble(4.33316);
    oos.writeInt(2);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then read it using your code, it should throw an EOFException.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more letters that integers/doubles, your code will go to the `EOFException`'s catch, but there you have no code regarding the EOF, but you print the largest/smallest values for some reason.

Since the EOF exception should only rise when you have more letters than numbers (since you are making your reads based on `word`'s length), you should move inside that catch your

```
System.out.println("Error in file: Length of string and numbers are not equal");
System.exit(0);
```